# In clearcase how to convert non modifiable baseline to modifiable?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

A new UCM project was created with multiple baselines configured

When i am trying to checkout files from particular component , I was not allowed to checkout and it said may be the stream will be read-only.

I am able to checkout other component files in the stream. So i tried to run the following command

> cleartool lsstream -view "MyBuildView" -l

Output had many things and the baseline related information i have copied below.

I am able to see that the component3 is non-modifiable as also it is not there in recommended baseline. (i added it separately as while creating the project it was missed)

```
foundation baselines:
  myProjc_RelBuild.1614@\my_PVOB (Compent1@\my_Pvob) (modifiable)
  myProj_RelBuild.5158@\my_Pvob (Component2@\my_Pvob) (modifiable)
  myProj_RelBuild.3209@\my_Pvob (Component3@\my_Pvob) (non-modifiable)
recommended baselines:
  myProjc_RelBuild.1614@\my_PVOB (Compent1@\my_Pvob) (modifiable)
  myProj_RelBuild.5158@\my_Pvob (Component2@\my_Pvob) (modifiable)
```

How to make component3 modifiable component? Is there any way i can ad as part of recommended baseline? Is it mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a:

```
 cleartool chproj -amodcomp Component3@\my_Pvob yourProject@\my_Pvob
```

You then should update your stream:

```
 ct chstream -generate stream:yourStream@\myPVob
```

And finally update the config spec of your view

```
 cd /path/to/your/view
 cleartool setcs -stream
```

Then you can try and checkout again.