# error while using clearfsimport to import files

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

learfsimport -rec -nset /view/abc_def/vobs/flo/floor/flore/flour/flow/fly/fi  .

```
ClearCase brtype is not guarded by a stream: brtype:....
clearfsimport: Warning: Trigger "checkin" has refused to let checkin proceed.
clearfsimport: Error: Could not checkin "
ClearCase brtype is not guarded by a stream: brtype:
clearfsimport: Warning: Trigger "checkin" has refused to let checkin proceed.
clearfsimport: Error: Could not checkin "".
clearfsimport: Warning: Trouble importing element "".
Creating element "".
```

Does anybody know why I am getting the error like above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the clearfsimport is done in a non-UCM view, for a file which is already part of an UCM component.

You need to use an UCM view as destination for the clearfsimport.

Comment: It is confirmed that the view is a UCM view. Does the component has to be modifiable to do this?

Comment: Yes, the component has to be modifiable for the clearfsimport to be able to update it. (modifiable in the project of the stream to which the view is attached to)

Comment: sorry. I didn't find the command to make it modifiable. Do you know how to make it modifiable since it is already created?

Comment: @user2370590 you can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427967/6309, you can see it in action in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1091075/6309